# CakePHP display custom fields from array

Tags: arrays, cakephp, filter

I know the title doesn't describe the best what I want to achieve, but I couldn't think of anything else.

Let's say I have the following array:

```
[Sender] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [username] => admin
                        [PrivateMessagesUser] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 1
                                [private_message_id] => 1
                                [sender_id] => 1
                                [recipient_id] => 3
                                [sender_status] => 1
                                [recipient_status] => 0
                                [random_key] => 
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [username] => admin
                        [PrivateMessagesUser] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 3
                                [private_message_id] => 1
                                [sender_id] => 1
                                [recipient_id] => 2
                                [sender_status] => 1
                                [recipient_status] => 0
                                [random_key] => 
                            )

                    )

            )
```

I am using the ContainableBehaviour to cut off extra data.
My problem is: how do I filter out the `Sender`s after a key which is present in `PrivateMessagesUser`? Say I need only the `Sender` where `PrivateMessagesUser.recipient_id = 3`.
I tried with

```
'Sender' => array( 
 'PrivateMessagesUser' => array(

 )
),
```

but it didn't work. Looks like I have to get over the [0], [1]... keys somehow and I don't know how.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here's how I obtain the array posted above:

```
$this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'PrivateMessage.id' => $this->__getUserPrivateMessagesInbox()
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Sender' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'username'),
                'PrivateMessagesUser' => array(
                    'fields' => array('PrivateMessagesUser.id')
                    //'conditions' => array('PrivateMessagesUser.recipient_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))
                )
            ),
            'Recipient' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'username'),
                'conditions' => array('Recipient.id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))
            )
        )
    );
```

How can I edit these lines in order to achieve the desired result?

**EDIT 2**

I am calling the paginate() from the PrivateMessagesController.

Associations:

User Model:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'PrivateMessageSent' => array(
        'className' => 'PrivateMessage',
        'joinTable' => 'private_messages_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'sender_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'private_message_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    ),
    'PrivateMessageReceived' => array(
        'className' => 'PrivateMessage',
        'joinTable' => 'private_messages_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'recipient_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'private_message_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

PrivateMessage Model:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Sender' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'private_messages_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'private_message_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'sender_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    ),
    'Recipient' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'private_messages_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'private_message_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'recipient_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    ),
);
```

PrivateMessagesUser Model:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'PrivateMessage' => array(
        'className' => 'PrivateMessage',
        'foreignKey' => 'private_message_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Sender' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'sender_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Recipient' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'recipient_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

And the database tables look like:

- `users`: `id`, `username`, ...
- `private_messages`: `id`, `subject`, ...
- `private_messages_users`: `id`, `private_message_id`, `sender_id`, `recipient_id`, `status`, ...

Comment: This does not make sense: A private message can have multiple senders? Multiple recipients seems common. Unless this is some form of threaded feature.

Comment: You're right, there is only one sender. But I thought if I have 2 different relations to the same model isn't right. How do you suggest changing these relations in order to both make sense and keep the functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to achieve this.

Looking at your returned data array, I'm guessing `PrivateMessagesUser` belongsTo `Sender`.

**1. Querying the PrivateMessagesUser model**

Sometimes, all it takes is querying the right model. You can apply the conditions directly to the model you want to apply your restrictions on.

```
$this->Sender->PrivateMessagesUser->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('PrivateMessagesUser.recipient_id' => 3),
    'contain' => array('Sender')
));
```

**2. Applying conditions to related models**

This doesn't work all the time, because CakePHP's SQL generation doesn't always work the way you want it to. But in simple cases like a hasMany relationship, you can use this:

```
$this->Sender->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('PrivateMessagesUser.recipient_id' => 3),
    'contain' => array('PrivateMessagesUser')
));
```

Again, this will work only if Cake executes a JOIN for the Containable parameters AND uses the conditions right.

**3. Using joins**

This method is foolproof but a little messy since it's highly customizable.

```
$this->Sender->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'private_messages_users',
            'alias' => 'PrivateMessagesUser',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'PrivateMessagesUser.sender_id = Sender.id',
                'PrivateMessagesUser.recipient_id' => 3
            )
        )
    )
));
```

---

My last piece of advice for you is to place this code into the Model. Follow the principle of "fat models, skinny controllers" whenever possible.

In the `Sender` model:

```
function fetchByRecipientId($recipientId) {
    ...
}
```

Good luck!

---

**EDIT:** In order to make this work for pagination, follow the methods above but use the following format:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'PrivateMessagesUser' => array(
        'conditions' => array('PrivateMessagesUser.recipient_id' => 3),
        'contain' => array('Sender'),
        // 'order' => ... other keys if you wish
    )
);
$this->set('senders', $this->paginate());
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to follow your last piece of advice. However, regarding my problem, it seems that the methods you provided won't work...I am calling that paginate() (find(), whatever) from the PrivateMessagesController. There is where I need to display the inbox of a user and therefore need to fetch all received messages together with sender. And the problem is that inside that paginate(), I cannot use `PrivateMessagesUser` model in the conditions because it outputs an "Field not found in where condition" error. Any other suggestion for dealing with this particular problem?

Comment: I've edited my answer to add the instructions for pagination. Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Worse, it selects all messages together with all their senders and recipients...(and I added the condition to select only certain private messages). The method I used gets all the messages received, together with their correct recipient (that means, current user). The problem is that it selects all senders of that message, together with the PrivateMessagesUser association, even if the recipient_id from the association is not the current user. My choice was to go "down" the associations and select only the sender which has the correct recipient_id.

Comment: The problem was that each Sender was displayed in an array, numerically indexed, so I didn't know how to "skip" this numerical index and go further in the associations array. Sorry, I know I don't explain very clearly the problem, but I have no other words for saying it.. :(

Comment: I would need the following information: 1) The controller you're calling paginate(), 2) The schema/relationships of all your related models.

Comment: I made a couple of changes (relationships between models) and called the paginate() from the PrivateMessagesUser Model instead of PrivateMessages Model. You were right. Now it works like a charm :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can put conditions inside Containable, like so:

```
$this->Sender->find('all', array(
   'contain' => array(
      'PrivateMessagesUser' => array('conditions' => array('recipient_id' => 3))
   )
));
```

EDIT:
Try modifying your `$this->paginate` as follow:

```
$this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'PrivateMessage.id' => $this->__getUserPrivateMessagesInbox()//array of message id's
        ),
        'fields' => array('PrivateMessagesUser.id'),
        'contain' => array(
            'Sender' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'username'),
            ),
            'Recipient' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'username'),
                'conditions' => array('Recipient.id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))
            )
        )
    )
```

Then call your paginate `$this->paginate($this->PrivateMessage)`

Comment: The idea is that I already have a find() query within whom I would like to get and filter all associated data.

Comment: then use Set?    Set::extract('/Sender/PrivateMessagesUser[recipient_id=3]', $originalData);

Comment: I wanted to filter out data before SQL interogation, so as not to fill the database with useless queries...

Comment: Hm, can you edit your question with your expected output? I still don't get what you want, sorry.

Comment: I mentioned that I want to filter the `Sender` s which match a given `PrivateMessagesUser.recipient_id`. I need to do this in one query. I also gave an example of what I tried and didn't work. My belief is because within `Sender`, I have numerous records and I don't know how to 'select' the arrays for each `Sender` (e.g. the ones with [0], [1], ...). Another thing which I think I didn't make it very clear is that the array displayed above is the **result** of the find(). I need to modify the find() in order to output the desired array, instead of the one I posted above.

Comment: So you want to select Senders based on PrivateMessagesUser.recipient_id ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to achieve. I'm sure it's done with Containable, but, as I said, I don't know how to 'enter' each of the Senders in order to be able to check the recipient_id

Comment: Can I see how you call your find with containable?

Comment: I've edited the question. Thank you for the interest shown :)

Comment: No problem, but I think RabidFire's solution might work for you already :D

Comment: Nope, your solution after your edit doesn't work...It says that PrivateMessagesUser.id is unknown...