# Contain Behavior, conditions and empty array

Tags: cakephp, model, behavior, contains

I have the next question.

There is part of code:

```
        $result = $this->find('all', array(
            'contain' => array(
                'User' => array(
                    'fields' => 'id',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'id' => $user_id
                    )
                )
            ),
            'fields' => 'url'
        ));
```

This find() called in method of Project model class and I want to retrieve just projects where User.id equal some user id passed to my method.
User HABTM Project and Project HABTM User.

But after executing I have the next:

```
app/views/projects/index.ctp (line 1)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://purpled.biz
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [ProjectsUser] => Array
                                (
                                    [user_id] => 4
                                    [project_id] => 1
                                    [projects_users_role_id] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://google.com
                    [id] => 2
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [ProjectsUser] => Array
                                (
                                    [user_id] => 4
                                    [project_id] => 2
                                    [projects_users_role_id] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://test.com
                    [id] => 3
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

As you see there is the last array with empty [User] array, so how can I exclude this empty array (whole [2] array I mean) without using foreach/if blocks? I know that using bindModel will do all as well but this is not for my question ;) So, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing your conditions within the 'contain' key will filter the results within that particular model.

**Retrieving the right data**
I've answered a question before very similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354846/cakephp-display-custom-fields-from-array/4355357#4355357). You would just need to replace the models mentioned there with your own models. If you have trouble understanding the answer there, let us know.

**Tips for your current model structure**
I notice that your ProjectsUser model has an extra field "projects_users_role_id". When your Join Model is complex (more than just id, model1_id, model2_id), then you need to represent it by a model in itself. It's generally referred to as a [hasMany Through](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1650/hasMany-through-The-Join-Model) relationship.

```
User hasMany ProjectsUser
Project hasMany ProjectsUser
ProjectsUserRole hasMany ProjectsUser

ProjectsUser belongsTo User
ProjectsUser belongsTo Project
ProjectsUser belongsTo ProjectsUserRole
```

You could also rename "ProjectsUser" to something nicer like "ProjectMembership".

Comment: Thanks! As result I used unbindModel/bindModel to create joins and contain for result array filtering.